# Real time animated plot on latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, animate

I would like to create a real-time animation figure with respect to the time in (s)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\scalebox{0.5}{
%\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.8\linewidth,
    height=1.2\linewidth,
    grid
    ,xlabel=Time (s)
    ,ylabel=\%MVC
    ,legend style={nodes={scale=1.8, transform shape}, at={(0.8,0.9)},anchor=west}
    ,axis x line = bottom,axis y line = left
    ,%={0,20,...,100}
    ,ymin=46, ymax=72, % or enlarge y limits=upper
    xmin=-4,xmax=125]

        \addplot+[const plot,color=red, mark=triangle*,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   70.853  )
(   0.689273    ,   70.853  )
(   6.059073    ,   65.0723 )
(   9.898123    ,   65.0723 )
(   19.716823   ,   63.82   )
(   27.423133   ,   63.1938 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.1938 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.1938 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.13   )
(   100.309753  ,   63.098  )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0821 )


    } node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

    \addlegendentry{$\overline{F_i}$}



\addplot+[const plot, color=black, mark=square,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   58.9965 )
(   0.689273    ,   65.0723 )
(   6.059073    ,   62.182  )
(   9.898123    ,   63.82   )
(   19.716823   ,   63.1938 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.8808 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.0506 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.13   )
(   74.194053   ,   63.098  )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0821 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0741 )



} node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

\addlegendentry{$F_{i}^{target}$}

    \addplot+[const plot,mark=*, color=green,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   47.1399 )
(   0.689273    ,   59.2917 )
(   6.059073    ,   59.2917 )
(   9.898123    ,   62.5677 )
(   19.716823   ,   62.5677 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.5677 )
(   28.424583   ,   62.9073 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.0661 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.0661 )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0661 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0661 )


} node[below,pos=.57, black] {};

\addlegendentry{$\underline{F_i}$}

    \node[ultra thick, color=black] at (3.8,135.5) {\textbf{${F_0}^{target}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=red] at (3.5,255) {\textbf{$\overline{F_0}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=green, ultra thick] at (5.2,15) {\textbf{$\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$}};

\draw [dashed, , thick] (5.2,12) -- (127,12);
\draw [>=stealth, <->] (126,12.2)--(126,169) node[midway,left, ultra thick] {$\overline{F_{10}}^{IDS}-\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Anyone for help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the time is in seconds, you can restrict the plot to the desired range by saying

```
\clip (-4,46) rectangle (\it,72);
```

where `\it` is the time counter. You need `clip mode=individual` to subject the plot marks to the clip. If my reading of the animate manual is correct, you need the `1` in `\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}` to achieve "real time".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage[export]{animate}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}
  \multiframe{120}{it=0+1}{\scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.8\linewidth,
    height=1.2\linewidth,
    grid
    ,xlabel=Time (s)
    ,ylabel=\%MVC
    ,legend style={nodes={scale=1.8, transform shape}, at={(0.8,0.9)},anchor=west,cells={anchor=west}}
    ,axis x line = bottom,axis y line = left
    ,ymin=46, ymax=72, % or enlarge y limits=upper
    xmin=-4,xmax=125,clip mode=individual]
\clip (-4,46) rectangle (\it,72);
        \addplot+[const plot,color=red, mark=triangle*,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   70.853  )
(   0.689273    ,   70.853  )
(   6.059073    ,   65.0723 )
(   9.898123    ,   65.0723 )
(   19.716823   ,   63.82   )
(   27.423133   ,   63.1938 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.1938 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.1938 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.13   )
(   100.309753  ,   63.098  )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0821 )


    } node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

    \addlegendentry{$\overline{F_i}$}



\addplot+[const plot, color=black, mark=square,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   58.9965 )
(   0.689273    ,   65.0723 )
(   6.059073    ,   62.182  )
(   9.898123    ,   63.82   )
(   19.716823   ,   63.1938 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.8808 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.0506 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.13   )
(   74.194053   ,   63.098  )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0821 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0741 )



} node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

\addlegendentry{$F_{i}^\mathrm{target}$}

    \addplot+[const plot,mark=*, color=green,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   47.1399 )
(   0.689273    ,   59.2917 )
(   6.059073    ,   59.2917 )
(   9.898123    ,   62.5677 )
(   19.716823   ,   62.5677 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.5677 )
(   28.424583   ,   62.9073 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.0661 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.0661 )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0661 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0661 )


} node[below,pos=.57, black] {};

\addlegendentry{$\underline{F_i}$}

    \node[ultra thick, color=black] at (3.8,135.5) {\textbf{${F_0}^{target}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=red] at (3.5,255) {\textbf{$\overline{F_0}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=green, ultra thick] at (5.2,15) {\textbf{$\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$}};

\draw [dashed, , thick] (5.2,12) -- (127,12);
\draw [>=stealth, <->] (126,12.2)--(126,169) node[midway,left, ultra thick] {$\overline{F_{10}}^{IDS}-\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The result is an animation that can be played with Acrobat Reader. In principle I could upload a gif but 120 steps makes it too large to be shown here. However, if one increases the step to two seconds, it becomes small enough to be uploaded.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage[export]{animate}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}
  \multiframe{60}{it=0+2}{\scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.8\linewidth,
    height=1.2\linewidth,
    grid,legend style={cells={anchor=west}},
    ,xlabel=Time (s)
    ,ylabel=\%MVC
    ,legend style={nodes={scale=1.8, transform shape}, at={(0.8,0.9)},anchor=west}
    ,axis x line = bottom,axis y line = left
    ,ymin=46, ymax=72, % or enlarge y limits=upper
    xmin=-4,xmax=125,clip mode=individual]
\clip (-4,46) rectangle (\it,72);
        \addplot+[const plot,color=red, mark=triangle*,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   70.853  )
(   0.689273    ,   70.853  )
(   6.059073    ,   65.0723 )
(   9.898123    ,   65.0723 )
(   19.716823   ,   63.82   )
(   27.423133   ,   63.1938 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.1938 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.1938 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.13   )
(   100.309753  ,   63.098  )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0821 )


    } node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

    \addlegendentry{$\overline{F_i}$}



\addplot+[const plot, color=black, mark=square,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   58.9965 )
(   0.689273    ,   65.0723 )
(   6.059073    ,   62.182  )
(   9.898123    ,   63.82   )
(   19.716823   ,   63.1938 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.8808 )
(   28.424583   ,   63.0506 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.13   )
(   74.194053   ,   63.098  )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0821 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0741 )



} node[below=1.15cm,pos=.76,black] {};

\addlegendentry{$F_{i}^\mathrm{target}$}

    \addplot+[const plot,mark=*, color=green,ultra thick] coordinates {

(   0.022531    ,   47.1399 )
(   0.689273    ,   59.2917 )
(   6.059073    ,   59.2917 )
(   9.898123    ,   62.5677 )
(   19.716823   ,   62.5677 )
(   27.423133   ,   62.5677 )
(   28.424583   ,   62.9073 )
(   36.398153   ,   63.0661 )
(   74.194053   ,   63.0661 )
(   100.309753  ,   63.0661 )
(   122.049853  ,   63.0661 )


} node[below,pos=.57, black] {};

\addlegendentry{$\underline{F_i}$}

    \node[ultra thick, color=black] at (3.8,135.5) {\textbf{${F_0}^{target}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=red] at (3.5,255) {\textbf{$\overline{F_0}$}};
\node[ultra thick, color=green, ultra thick] at (5.2,15) {\textbf{$\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$}};

\draw [dashed, , thick] (5.2,12) -- (127,12);
\draw [>=stealth, <->] (126,12.2)--(126,169) node[midway,left, ultra thick] {$\overline{F_{10}}^{IDS}-\underline{F_0}^{SALBP-1}$};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, you can put \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
 instead of \scalebox{0.5}{}. +1

Comment: @M.Ahmadi Thanks! I thought about this but recently I tended to get rather hefty reactions when doing such changes. So I contented myself with fixing the legend. Yet you are right, using `scale=0.5,transform shape` plus a few more keys that rescale the pgfplots stuff and the line widths would be the way cleaner option if the OP ever attempted to a access the nodes from outside. I speculate that they do not want to do that, so I let it be. But again I really appreciate the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help !. It turns out that it's too slow in real-time, how can I speed up more than 2s ! to have the full picture within 5s for instance. Thank you

Comment: @AmineAbdous According to the manual, `1` in `\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}` is the rate. So if you want to have 120 frames in 5 seconds, the rate should be `24`, i.e. I'd assume you need `\begin{animateinline}[controls]{24}` instead.